# Is there a way to disable all browser-like behaviors in an electron app?

Tags: electron

I'm writing a desktop app using Electron and I find that there are different behaviors that are commonplace in a browser that I would not like present in a desktop app.

(eg. Drag-and-drop file to load in electron window; user-select; Ctrl+R to refresh; etc.)

I know how to disable these but how do I know I've gotten them all? Is there are way to just disable every user-interaction? Otherwise there might be one I'm not thinking of that could potentially mess up the application.

Comment: Good question! As far as I've seen it from the docs the only way to prevent these behaviors are by disabling them individually or using the `unregisterAll` function on globalShortcut. This would make a good issue on GitHub.